# Generate Orders w/ Quotes/Opportunities (Salesforce Lab)

Tags: flow

I was trying out the Salesforce labs Generate Orders w/ Quotes/Opportunities https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5iwHEAR I am trying to modify the Quote to Contract Flow and in the fast lookup of Quotes i am trying get the Contractid field into a variable. But somehow that field is not available when i search for it to save the record values in a variable. Looks like contractid was preselected in the flow but somehow in my sandbox it doesnt seem to be available in the flow.

Is there some other setting to activate Contract from Quotes? I did check the FLS and it was not visible. i changed to be visible  but still i cant see the contract id on the flow.

Any idea what could be issue.
[image]